# Can't run Selenium in replit.com

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used Selenium previously on replit.com and it still works in other repls. When I create a new repl I get this error, I don't know why

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

The error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/w/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/runner/w/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/runner/w/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/runner/w/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add to this code line

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

The path where your `chromedriver.exe` file is located.
Something like the following:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/to/folder/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your cooperation. I am working on a replit site. I don't know how to locate the chromedriver.exe file

Comment: I mean the location of selenium `chromedriver.exe` file on YOUR computer.